# taking the argument (input) after a character in sys.argv[]?

Tags: python

I have a simple code to get user email information, I got a problem about something :

```
import sys
try:
    argx = sys.argv(1)
except:
    print("Please Input an email.")
```

Example For User argument :
py main.py example@example.com
I want to take arg (input) after the `@` char and the `.` char.
I need this to check the email provider, domain name and other stuff about the email.

`Example of the thing i want :`

```
import sys
try:
    argx = sys.argv(1)
    x = "The argument after the char @, and the ."

except:
    print("Please Input an email.")

if(x.lower() == "gmail") :
    gmail()
elif(x.lower == "protonmail") :
    protonmail()
```

Comment: Should be `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: You should state what happens when you run that you didnt want to happen

Comment: Also the reason you didnt realise you made a Syntax mistake with sys.argv(1) was you had a plain except with no specific exception. Its recommended to except specific exceptions only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` function of a string in order to split a string
like

```
x = 'name@example.com' #Your input
email = x.split('@') # will give ['name','example.com']
provider = email[1].split('.')[0] # will give 'example'
```

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you have the following email `example@example.com`. In python you can split a string with the split function. The function itself needs a delimeter. In your case the delimeter would be `@`. The return value of the split function is an array.

```
parts_of_mail = email.split("@")
>>> [example, example.com]
```

You now have the array `parts_of_mail`, which stores the left and right part of the email. You can now split the string again, like above:

```
provider_info = parts_of_mail[1].split(".")
>>> [example, com]
```

Finally you can check the provider information:

```
if provider_info[0].lower() == "example":
    # do stuff here
elif provider_info[0].lower() == "gmail":
    # do stuff here
```

**Note:** `provider_info[0]` stores the provider and `provider_info[1]` stores the domain.